# why we need property/getter/setter in python?

Tags: python

Just want to undertstand property/getter/setter in python. Two questions on hand, could you please help to answer? Thanks.

1. Go through several threads, basic knowledge is we can use the getter/setter to make some attributes private, then by using property, we can use these attributes like public. So why we need this? since original `__init__` is public
2. Several thread give us the example that we can add value constraint inside setter. My question is  why we not add constraint inside `__init__` directly just like code below?

```
class test1:
  def __init__(self, num):
     if type(num) == int:
         self.num = num
     else:
         raise TypeError('we need int')
```

Comment: `__init__` is not the only place where you assign attributes, it's just for initializing them when you first create the instance.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Yes, we can initialize attributes iniside __init__, so why we still need property/getters/setters? since we can get/set from test1, also we can check attributes inside __init__. (property will make attribute as public I think

Comment: You need them so you can change the attributes later.

Comment: `__` is the markdown for bold text, put `__init__` inside backticks so it will show up properly.

Comment: Private attributes are written using `_` prefix, e.g. `self._num = num`

Comment: "You need them so you can change the attributes later." So if we not change these attributes, we don't need property/setter/getter?? if we want to change them, why we not add more method inside class to change?

Comment: That's what setters and getters are, methods in the class to change them.

Comment: They just let you call them as if you're assigning the attribute. It hides the fact that you're using a method.

Comment: So, it's not related to private. The main reason of python using this is we can change attribute inside class?

Comment: The purpose of getters and setters is so you can use methods to emulate attributes.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. "It hides the fact that you're using a method."  why we need to hides these? since we can do all the thing in `__init__`? Any thing we can not do inside `__init__` and we can do by using getter/setter?

Comment: Forget about `__init__`, it's irrelevant. Getters and setters are accessing and updating properties of objects that have already been created.

Comment: Why is this question so fixated on ˋ__init__ˋ? There are many cases where attributes are read or written outside of ˋ__init__ˋ.

Comment: Because many thread discuss this by starting `__init__`, so I confused and want to compare these. Thanks all, will read more and try to understand this more deeply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need them in the first place - as you wrote, you can just use instance variables:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.the_answer = 42
```

But if you later change the implementation to use a function instead of a variable, you can change that to:

```
def __init__(self):
    self._the_answer = None

@property
def the_answer(self):
    if self._the_answer is None:
         self._the answer = self.calculate_answer() 
    return self._the_answer
```

without changing the API. In this example, it is using lazy evaluation to make the calculation only on access, but there are a lot of other cases where this can be helpful:

- calculate the property value from several variables, so no single variable is needed
- add constraints to the setter to only allow setting certain values
- do not add a setter to have read-only attributes
- invalidate the value on certain events and re-calculate them only in this case
- overwrite the behavior of attributes in subclasses

Comment: Thanks MrBean. So we can say: 1. the reason why we use property is we can make our code "backward compatible"? 2. When we design API, we'd better to add @property inside our class?

Comment: You can add them as you need them, you can start with instance variables if that serves you. Simpler is better...

Comment: Now you are missing a target in the assignment.